# What is starvation mode?

Tags: nutrition

I lift weights but sometimes I'm so tired I forget to take dinner because I end up asleep in bed after showering, then I go without eating until next day's lunch time. And I feel light headed before eating and all round slower when moving. Is this starvation mode?

And is it true that whatever I eat after this will be stored as fat in the body?

Answer (score 3):

Starvation mode is your body's response to a lack of food intake, not the absence of.  The body throttles down your metabolism in order to save energy.  This response is your body's way of saying, "I don't know when my next meal is coming in, I need to conserve."

I don't think you are in "starvation mode." I do think that your body is running low on energy and since you haven't eaten in such a long time your body is just feeling neglected. However, if you feel like this is becoming more and more of an issue you need to take it up with your primary care physician or a registered dietitian.

Comment: "Starvation mode" is a myth among dieters, usually hauled out when metabolisms start adjusting and weight loss slows down. True starvation mode takes a long time to get to, and is extremely debilitating.